# Get credentials of active Team Explorer from Addin VS 2008

Tags: tfs, credentials, visual-studio-addins, team-explorer

I have VS 2008 and Team Explorer, and TFS.

I open VS 2008 using a local administrator (MACHINE\admin). I open Team Explorer to connect to TFS Server using domain user (DOMAIN\user). The login dialog appears when I connect to TFS in Team Explorer (I put login and password).

Now, in my addin, programatically I want connect to TFS.

How can I get the credentials (that I introduce in login dialog in Team Explorer) to connect to TFS ?

Reference:
How to get the active Team Foundation Server and Project from an Add-In
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/hippietim/archive/2006/03/29/563988.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
System.Net.NetworkCredential credential = (System.Net.NetworkCredential)System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
```

Aside from that, you could setup an account that the addin could run under using :

```
new NetworkCredential(username,password,domain)
```

System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials may pass back the admin creds though.  In which case, creating an account for the addin to run under would still be an option.